# Dynamic aliases to host in ssh config

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

Imagine we have dynamic number of hosts of pattern

`test-1.mydomain.com

test-2.mydomain.com

test-3.mydomain.com

...

test-n.mydomain.com`

I'd like to ssh on each of those machines by not using full name

`ex. ssh test-7.mydomain.com`

but simply by doing

`ssh test-7`

Is there a way to use ssh config to do pattern like aliases like this??

Answer (score 2):

### Yes!

Yes, there is a way to do this directly in your ssh configuration.

1. `host` allows [PATTERNS](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#PATTERNS)
2. `hostname` allows [TOKENS](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#TOKENS)

### How:

Add this snippet to your ssh configuration `~/.ssh/config`:

```sh
# all test-* hosts should match to test-*.mydomain.example.com
host test-*
    hostname %h.mydomain.example.com
```

### Verify:

You can verify this with the `-G` flag to ssh.  If your ssh is older and does not support `-G` you can try parsing verbose ssh output.

```sh
# if your ssh supports -G
% ssh test-17 -G | grep hostname
hostname test-17.mydomain.example.com


# if your ssh does not support -G
% ssh -v -v test-n blarg >/dev/null 2>&1 | grep resolv
debug2: resolving "test-n.mydomain.example.com" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname test-n.mydomain.example.com: Name or service not known
```

### Notes:

Ssh uses the *first* host line that matches.  It is good practice to add your PATTERN host lines at the bottom of your configuration file.

If your `test-n` name patterns contain only a single character suffix, then you can use a `?` pattern to make a less greedy match.  `test-?` will match `test-1` `test-a` `test-z` but not `test-10`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ssh config file and pre setting your servers.

See this tutorial, i hope it helps you!

[ssh config](https://www.howtogeek.com/75007/stupid-geek-tricks-use-your-ssh-config-file-to-create-aliases-for-hosts/)

You can also create a function in your bash file for ssh access.

Like this:

```
function ssh_test () {
  [[ $1 =~ ^('test-1'|'test-2'|'test-3')$ ]] || { echo 'Not a valid value !!' && return ;}
  domain=$1.mydomain.com
  ssh my_user@"$domain" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option for you, you could add a search domain in the [`resolv.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) file (I'm assuming you are on Linux).

You would need to add a line like this:

```
search mydomain.com
```

which will have SSH (and most other apps) look for `test-n`, then `test-n.mydomain.com`.

If you are not managing the `resolv.conf` file yourself (if you use systemd-networkd or NetworkManager for example), you will have to ajust the search domains in their configuration files).